# KDE Plasma changes brightness on wrong GPU

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma, plasma5, brightness

I am able to change brightness manually by issuing the command:

```bsh
echo 512 | sudo tee - /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This changes the brightness output of my Intel integrated GPU on my laptop. However, this laptop also has a dedicated NVIDIA video card which also has a backlight section:

```
/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
```

The problem is that when I change the brightness using the brightness changing hotkeys, Plasma (or whatever program is responsible for changing brightness) thinks it should change the brightness in the nvidia_0 section of the backlight instead of the intel_backlight. How do I fix this? BTW I'm running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a fix is coming with Plasma 5.25 (scheduled to be released on June 14): https://invent.kde.org/plasma/powerdevil/-/commit/761fc8a4bf4bd70bcd9aca63fc67382c94ecf884